# Run programmes in a sequence using python

Tags: python, command-line

I have a python programme as below

```
import os
import subprocess
for m in range(0,10):
    os.chdir("C:/")
    run="my command%d"%m
    subprocess.Popen(run).wait()
```

Where 'my command' is something I used to launch another programme.
Although I have wait() after Popen, it turns out that the 10 programmes still run simultaneously, not as expected.
How do I settle this issue?

Comment: What are the commands you are running? If they fork, then POpen may only wait on the parent process.

Comment: I tried it and it works fine. As command I have used "ping www.SomeWebSite.pq"

Comment: I am new to programming, could you explain a bit on 'fork'? And is there any way to wait for parent process?

Comment: What is my command in your case?

Comment: My command is to use a Tcl programme to calculate something.

Comment: To be more specific, it is   tclsh oommf.tcl oxsii abc.mif     where oommf.tcl is the one I used for calculation and abc.mif is the input

Comment: Using `wait` is the cause to the sequential nature, right? From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait): `Popen.wait()
Wait for child process to terminate. Set and return returncode attribute.`

Comment: @justhalf I wish to achieve sequential performance, but it failed to do so...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I read it as you wanted it to be simultaneous. How do you know that it's running simultaneously?

Comment: @justhalf There is actually a graphical interface whereby I can monitor the output data. I noticed that output of several programmes were generated at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

- use `subprocess.check_call()` (which should run sequentially)
- use `Popen.communicate()` ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) with `stdout` and `stderr` set to `subprocess.PIPE` to see if stdout and stderr are indeed sequentially generated

Also, `datetime.datetime.now()` gives you a microsecond, so you can see time with granularity higher than 1s.